# Print a Word document from VARBINARY(MAX) column

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, printing, binaryfiles

I created a dynamic form site like Google Form, one of the requirements is that on each survey I could attach a Word file that should be printed after I print the survey form.

So, after I download the file from the database what do I have to do to print it?

Example code:

```
private void downloadFile()
{
    string item = Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString();
    SQL sql_files = new SQL(ConnectionStringName.FilesSqlServer);

    sql_files.ExecuteStoreProcedure(SqlStoreProcedureNames.spFileStorage, SqlOutputType.DataReader, new SQLParameter[]{
        new SQLParameter(ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.VarChar, "@IdRespuesta", Session["id_respuesta"].ToString()),
        new SQLParameter(ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.VarChar, "@ItemID", item),
        new SQLParameter(ParameterDirection.Output, SqlDbType.VarChar, "@SpError")
    });

    if (sql_files.Reader.HasRows)
    {
        sql_files.Reader.Read();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sql_files.Reader["name"].ToString());

        Response.ContentType = sql_files.Reader["contenttype"].ToString();
        byte[] fileBytes = (byte[])sql_files.Reader["bytes"];

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    sql_files.Reader.Close();
}
```

I use this code to download the file, so I need to change it so I can print a Word document.

Greetings,
Clark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code downloads a file to a client machine. You cannot control the printing. It all depends on client. Do you actually want to print it on a printer or you mean something different?
**Edit:**
There's no way to show printing dialog to a user, since it is browser specific.
One thing you can try is to use `--kiosk`and`--kiosk-printing` prefixes for Chrome 18+.

**Note** that you cannot run any code after Response.End() without causing a request from a user. if you want to run any code after Response.End() you will have to use IFrame or WebHandler.